# Can I use environment variables in vim keyboard mappings?

Tags: windows, environment-variables, vim

There's probably a better way to do this, but this is what I'm trying to do. I have several html files for which I need to update meta tags prior to updating the content. I'm trying to automate this by using a keyboard mapping similar to what follows:

```
nnoremap <leader>mt /<meta name="developer"<cr>f";;lct"$username
```

This seems to work with the exception of the `$username` portion. How can I make the mapping evaluate the variable?

I do have a few tags to update per page, but don't know how else to do this. If someone has a better method, I'd be more than happy to hear it. The content that I'm searching through is similar to the following:

```
<meta name="owner" content="someowner">
<meta name="developer" content="somedev">
<meta name="date" content="2012-07-26">
<meta name="expires" content="2013-07-26">
```

The `date` would be the date that I opened the file to edit, while the `expires` would be one year from the `date`

NOTE: This is gvim on Windows if that changes things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$username` does refer to the environment variable `username`, but to use this in a mapping, you have to stick to the (somewhat unintuitive, but perfectly consistent) interpretation rules of Vim.

The `ct"` mean *change until double-quote*, so what follows is in insert mode. To insert an environment variable (or any other Vim expression), use `<C-R>=`:

```
nnoremap <leader>mt /<meta name="developer"<cr>f";;lct"<C-R>=$username<CR>
```

This will evaluate the environment variable on each mapping invocation. (And stay in insert mode; append `<Esc>` to go back to normal mode!) Alternatively, you could also bake the value into the mapping itself:

```
execute 'nnoremap <leader>mt /<meta name="developer"<cr>f";;lct"' . $username
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but for the user name on a unix machine you can call the 'whoami' command as external command from vim and store it's return value in a variable for later reuse

For the dates, there is a strftime() function in vim. You could add an auto command for the VimEnter event and store the time/date at that moment in a variable too, to reuse it later.